# Why is pow() reporting an infinite value in this case?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using the `pow()` function like this in my application:

```
float  IValuePlusOne =  (pow(2.25,120));
```

but it is reporting back an infinite value, instead of the correct result.  I even tried the `long long` and `long double` data types but couldn't get them to produce the proper output.

Is there any other data type I need to use or do I need to make some other changes in my code?

Comment: This answer (1.828*10^42) will fit into a `double`.

Comment: Doesn't pow return a double?
Also: What does it mean when you say that it gives you no value?

Comment: Have you executed the above line onto xcode.As when i did i got inf value for IValuePlusOne after its execution.If you can execute the code at your end you will come know about the problem .

Comment: I was pointing out that the statement "But this doesn't give me any value" is ambiguous. A value of +Infinity is a general error code and that would have provided me some information to help you. It is not my job to execute your code for you, but to assist you in understanding your problem.
Your answer does not fit in the type to which it is being assigned.

Comment: @zeychin sorry for that.But is there any solution to this as i am getting inf please help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you're losing precision and reducing the size of value you can represent by casting to a float.  Running the following code:

```
double IValuePlusOne = pow(2.25,120.0);
NSLog(@"Test value: %f", IValuePlusOne);
```

on my iPhone gives the output:

> Test value: 1827688475348373523156051712429585892114432.000000

which looks to be correct (1.827x10^42).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do calculations on values that a double can't hold, use [`NSDecimalNumber`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html).